# Accessing value from searchbar in server?

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to get the value entered by a user from my search form in the html page from my server.js page and can't figure out how. I know that the name/value pair will be cityCode=something but don't know what to do from there?

HTML:

```
      <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0" id="form" action="/hotels" method="GET">
        <!-- location search bar -->
        <input
          class="form-control mr-sm-2"
          type="text"
          placeholder="Search Location"
          aria-label="Search"
          id="searchbar"
          name="cityCode"
        >
        <!-- end of location search bar-->

        <!-- start of location search button -->
        <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit" id="searchbutton">
          Search
        </button>
        <!-- end of location search button-->
      </form>
```

server.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.use(express.static('public'));
var Amadeus = require('amadeus');

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.listen(8080);

app.get('/hotels', function(req, res){
    amadeus.shopping.hotelOffers.get({
    //'PAR' to be replaced by user input
        cityCode: 'PAR'
    }).then(function(response){
    var jsonData = JSON.parse(response.body);

    res.render('pages/onestar', {jsonData: JSON.stringify(jsonData.data[1].type)});

    }).catch(function(error){
      console.log(error.response); //=> The response object with (un)parsed data
      //console.log(error.response.request); //=> The details of the request made
      console.log(error.code); //=> A unique error code to identify the type of error
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your form is using method `GET`, your submit will send `cityCode` as a query parameter. To access that in Express, use `req.query`:

```
app.get('/hotels', async function(req, res, next) {
  try {
    const response = await amadeus.shopping.hotelOffers.get({
      cityCode: req.query.cityCode
    });
    const jsonData = JSON.parse(response.body);
    res.render('pages/onestar', {jsonData: JSON.stringify(jsonData.data[1].type)});
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.response); //=> The response object with (un)parsed data
    //console.log(error.response.request); //=> The details of the request made
    console.log(error.code); //=> A unique error code to identify the type of error
    next(error);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to make a `GET` request from your html page using JavaScript to the assigned route on your Node.js server. You can do something like this:

```
    function sendSearch() { 
      let term = document.getElementById("searchbar").value;
      fetch('<your server address>/hotels?search=' + term).then( response => {
        //do something with the response
      };
    }
```

You can call that function on the `onsubmit` event of your form, like `onsubmit='sendSearch()'`, or on the `onclick` event of the button.

And in your server.js, get the query params like this:

```
   app.get('/hotels', function(req, res){
     let searchTerm = req.query.search;
     ...
```

Then you can use the query params inside your `GET` function.